# how to remove html tags in php?

Tags: php, symfony1

i posted some data using tinymce (in a symfony project).while retrieving back how can i remove html tags? strip_tags not working..

Comment: "strip_tags not working" - works for me. What did you test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easies way is to use `strip_tags` but it's not very reliable. There is a very, very, VERY good project design specifically for this: **[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)**.

It battle-hardened, tested and very good. `strip_tags` is the easy, fast and go way, but it can miss out some malformated html that a browser will actually parse and execute.

---

Please, don't use regular expression to parse html!

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful information share 'Emil'. I will use it in my next project.

Answer (score 3):

Note that strip_tags returns a **new** string. It does not modify the original string, i.e:

```
$html = '<p>Test</p>';
strip_tags($html); // Throws away the result, since you don't assign the return 
                   // value of the function to a variable

$stripped = strip_tags($html);
echo $stripped; // echos 'Test'
```

Comment: That is pretty default behavior, isn't it? Not worth mentioning. It's a fine example though.

Comment: Yes, it is very much the default behaviour. Just thought it was worth mentioning since "it doesn't work" without any code sample doesn't give us much to go on

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo strip_tags($this->getContent(ESC_RAW))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)**:

```
strip_tags('your text or variable');
```

It should **work** in symfony. Make sure that you have done everything correctly.

Comment: i gave for ex: echo strip_tags($var); then it is printing all the html tags also

Answer (score 1):

When using Symfony, be sure to use the getRaw() function otherwise the text cannot be stripped from it's HTML code, for example:

> $myText = $sf_data->getRaw('myVarContainingText');

Then use strip_tags() as such:

> $myText = strip_tags( $sf_data->getRaw('myVarContainingText') );

Answer (score 1):

strip_tags(); you need to put what ever your $ is wrapped with html. ...........