# php string avoid bold italic etc

Tags: php

I tried googling this, but no luck. Didn't know how to phrase it, lmfao. But anyway, I have this article:

http://puu.sh/1CDtq

But it shows the bold, italics etc(which messes up the default CSS for the styled articles, when it should actually just show up here: http://puu.sh/1CDwk (which is good)). What I'm asking is how would I go about trying to not to decode html entities? and to just show default text for the news_content?

This is the code:

```
<?php echo substr($row['news_content'], 0, 150). "...... <a href=''>(Read More)</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove html tags in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432042/how-to-remove-html-tags-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

use `strip_tags()` function in php

```
echo substr(strip_tags($row['news_content']), 0, 150). "...... <a href=''>(Read More)</a>";
```

Comment: And do this before truncating the length, rather than after - so that the resulting length includes only the text remaining after strip_tags.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo substr(strip_tags($row['news_content']), 0, 150). "...... <a href=''>(Read More)</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: wow. I cannot believe I didn't get that. Thanks man.

Comment: If you do strip_tags *after* substr, like this, you may end up with half a tag at the end of the string, which could mess up your HTML.  Also, you would probably prefer the HTML tags not to be counted in the 150 character limit, which is another reason to strip_tags before substr.

Answer (score 1):

Don't format the content inline - use a stylesheet for content pages. Then on the main page that shortens all of the posts, use a special stylesheet that ignores the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to truncating the length of the HTML string, you need to convert it back to text.

You can do this with `strip_tags`, followed by `html_entity_decode`.

Using html_entity_decode is a good idea since otherwise, truncating the string could cut the string part way through an HTML entity, like `&nbsp;`.

Doing both before truncating the string is a good idea so that the HTML tags and entities aren't included in the length of the resulting string, and that they cannot be chopped in half accidentally.

Here's an overall example:

```
function gettextexcerpt($myhtml, $len = 150) {
    $myhtml = html_entity_decode(strip_tags($myhtml), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    return substr($myhtml, 0, $len);
};
```

Change `UTF-8` if you are using a different character encoding for text.